# Error in lapply() in R

Tags: r, lapply

I have been trying to analyze my Kallisto Quant data using an R markdown code passed down from someone who did this recently. However, unlike their output, I have been getting an error saying that the object 'kallistoData' is not found for the same code.

````
```{r 1, warning=FALSE}
setwd("~/Desktop/KallistoQuant/1")
## this will create lists of all the samples
kallistoDirs = dir(".")
kallistoDirs = kallistoDirs[!grepl("\\.(R|py|pl|sh|xlsx?
|txt|tsv|csv|org|md|obo|png|jpg|pdf)$",
                              kallistoDirs,
                              ignore.case=TRUE)]

kallistoFiles = paste0(kallistoDirs, "/abundance.tsv")

names(kallistoFiles) = kallistoDirs

if(file.exists(kallistoFiles))
  kallistoData = lapply(kallistoFiles,
                    read.table,
                    sep = "\t",
                    row.names = 1,
                    header = TRUE)

## this for loop uses the reduce function to make two data frame with counts or tpm from all the samples
ids = Reduce(f=union, x=lapply(kallistoData, rownames))

## ^this is where I see the error

if (all(sapply(kallistoData, function(x) {all(rownames(x)==ids)})))
{
    count = data.frame(
    id = ids,
sapply(kallistoData, function(x) {x$est_counts}),
check.names = FALSE,
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

tpm = data.frame(id = ids,
                sapply(kallistoData,
                function(x) {x$tpm}),
                check.names = FALSE,
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}

row.names(count) <- count$id
count[1] <- NULL

row.names(tpm) <- tpm$id
tpm[1] <- NULL

write.csv(count, "../1.csv", row.names=T)
write.csv(tpm, "../1TPM.csv", row.names=T)
```
````

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Well, your definition of `kallistoData` is wrapped inside `if (file.exists(kallistoFiles))`, so maybe the `kallistoFiles` file doesn't exist. I would suggest running your code one line at a time and inspecting the variables defined to try to see the earliest things don't look right.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I ran each line but I do see outputs for both kallistoDirs and kallistoFiles.